# how to code initializer(random.uniform) in custom layers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, initialization

I want to initialize my custom layer with random uniform. In TensorFlow，I can find following code which use `initializer='uniform'`. But I want to set random uniform output range between `(-1.0,1.0)`. How to do that:

```
class MyDenseLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, num_outputs):
    super(MyDenseLayer, self).__init__()
    self.num_outputs = num_outputs

  def build(self, input_shape):
    self.kernel = self.add_variable(initializer='uniform',shape=[int(input_shape[-1]),self.num_outputs])

  def call(self, input):
    return tf.matmul(input, self.kernel)
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is to generate random uniform in `numpy` and then use `tf.constant_initializer()` like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class MyDenseLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_outputs):
        super(MyDenseLayer, self).__init__()
        self.num_outputs = num_outputs

    def build(self, input_shape):
        shape = [int(input_shape[-1]),self.num_outputs]
        init_val = np.random.uniform(low=-1.0, high=1.0, size=shape)
        initializer = tf.constant_initializer(init_val,
                                              dtype=tf.float32)
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(initializer=initializer,
                                      shape=shape,
                                      name='kernel')
        super(MyDenseLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, input):
        return tf.matmul(input, self.kernel)
```

**OR** use `tf.initializers.random_uniform()` instead

```py
init = tf.initializers.random_uniform(minval=-1.0, maxval=1.0)
self.kernel = self.add_weight(initializer=init,
                              shape=shape,
                              name='kernel')
```